# Extension method & LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, extension-methods, dto

While trying to map an entity to an DTO i get the following error.

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Dto.Team
>   ToTeamDto(Team, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression."

Here is the query

```
 bool includeTeam = true;

 var source = from c in db.Standings
                         where c.LeagueID == leagueId
                         select new Standing
                         {
                             id = c.StandingsId,
                             team = includeTeam ? c.Team.ToTeamDto("en-US") : null
                         };
```

and the extension method

```
        internal static Dto.Team ToTeamDto(this Team team, string locale)
        {
            return new Dto.Team
            {
                id = team.TeamID,
                name = team.name
            };
        }
```

What is wrong with this one?
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that EF cannot translate your function into SQL. The easiest solution is to materialise the data with `ToList` then use your function:

```
var source = db.Standings
             .Where(c => c.LeagueID == leagueId)
             .ToList()
             .Select(c => new Standing
             {
                 id = c.id,
                 team = includeTeam ? c.Team.ToTeamDto("en-US") : null,
                 //other properties here
             });
```

Comment: There must be an easier workaround than this? I mean the Standing class has more than 30 properties, excluded from the example above for simplicity

Comment: You cannot pass the `ToTeamDto` method into an EF query. You could embed that code in the query.

Comment: I've simplified it a little bit

Comment: My first implementation was embedding the query in the EF query. My second thought was using an extension method since other queries may use this one as well. But when i read your first comment i said oh my.. i have 30+ issues. It works like a charm now! Thanks!