# LINQ to Entities - create median value in grouped data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, grouping

I have a LINQ to Entities query for grouping data and add some aggregations at the same time and it works except the median value calculation. Median value is calculated on sorted columns divided by 2 (get the middle value from the column). Here is my example:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var query = from t in _database.jon_export
                    orderby t.businessEmployeeCount
                    group t by t.county.ToString() into g
                    where g.Count() > 0
                    select new
                    {
                        County = g.Key,
                        CountValue = g.Count(),
                        BusinessEmployeeCount = g.Count(),
                        BusinessEmployeeAverageValue = g.Average(x => x.businessEmployeeCount),
                        //Median value from businessEmployeeCount column
                        BusinessRevenueAverageValue = g.Average(x => x.businessRevenue),  
                        BusinessTurnover=g.Average(x => x.businessTurnover),
                        BooiqEconomicWellBeing=g.Average(x=>x.booiqEconomicWellBeing)
                    };
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write an extension method on IEnumerable and call that extension method in the code with the right property.

```
public static double Median(this IEnumerable<int> items)
{
    var data = items.OrderBy(n => n).ToArray();
    if (data.Length % 2 == 0)
        return (data[data.Length / 2 - 1] + data[data.Length / 2]) / 2.0;
    return data[data.Length / 2];
}
```

and later in the above-mentioned snippet add as follows:

```
businessEmployeeMedian =  g.Select(x => x.businessEmployeeCount).Median(),
```

For skipping businessEmployeeCount with null

```
businessEmployeeMedian = g.Where(x => x.businessEmployeeCount.HasValue).Select(x => (int)x.businessEmployeeCount).Median()
```

Complete linq in method syntax

```
            var items = _database.jon_export
            .OrderBy(item => item.businessEmployeeCount)
            .GroupBy(item => item.County)
            .Where(g => g.Any())
            .Select(g => {
                return new
                {
                    County = g.Key,
                    CountValue = g.Count(),
                    BusinessEmployeeCount = g.Count(),
                    BusinessEmployeeAverageValue = g.Average(x => x.businessEmployeeCount),
                    businessEmployeeMedian = g.Where(x => x.businessEmployeeCount.HasValue).Select(x => (int)x.businessEmployeeCount).Median(),
                    BusinessRevenueAverageValue = g.Average(x => x.businessRevenue),
                    BusinessTurnover = g.Average(x => x.businessTurnover),
                    BooiqEconomicWellBeing = g.Average(x => x.booiqEconomicWellBeing)
                };
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: I got this message: CS1061 'IEnumerable<int?>' does not contain a definition for and no accessible extension method 'Median' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<int?>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: do you want to take null as 0 ? or would like to ignore them while trying to calculate median?

Comment: I would like to ignore them. Like skip NULLs in the rows. Also, how to structure this extension method with this keyword?

Comment: for ignoring null values you can add another where clause 
`businessEmployeeMedian =  g.Where(x => x.businessEmployeeCount.HasValue).Select(x => (int)x.businessEmployeeCount).Median()`

Comment: @MunirHadrovic i did not get what are you asking.
"how to structure this extension method with this keyword?"

[reference for extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

Comment: Error CS1106 Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

Comment: You should place the extension in another static class. Not the same class in which button2_click is.

Comment: I got this on this.dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();     - Message=LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double GetMedian(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
  Source=EntityFramework

Comment: From this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42741529/extension-method-linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-error) looks like the linq is unable to convert the new custom extension method to SQL.

need to add ToList() before where clause in the query. For that, we might need to use linq method syntax instead of linq query syntax.

Comment: Very interesting. How to do that?

Comment: LINQ methods are the same only syntaxes differ. This [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42741529/extension-method-linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-error) will help you with that .

Comment: Not working. How to add grouping and custom names for my results? Thanks

Comment: Could you please add your new method snippet to the question?

Comment: How to rewrite this not to lose grouping?